# Download files from gnome-look.org via CLI

Tags: shell-script, command-line, curl

I can [download extensions from https://extensions.gnome.org/ or https://cinnamon-spices.linuxmint.com/ using curl](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/707840/206574). However, I am unable to do it from https://www.gnome-look.org

To be specific, I am trying to download the zip files from https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1309239 and https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1308808

I found that the download links look like https://files03.pling.com/api/files/download/j/eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpZCI6MTY3OTUwODg0MywidSI6bnVsbCwibHQiOiJkb3dubG9hZCIsInMiOiI1YWI5OWZkYjg3ZDMxYTlmYzEwZTdjNGE5YTQ0YTE2ZTdmNDI5ZDVhOTFkYzI3MGVhNzZhYTE1OTg2ZTQ1YmIwYjNjZDM3NTYwMjU4ZDJkMzQ1YWY2ZDNiMWFmZTcxNDA4NTU2OTc4Zjg3ZWFkN2EyMzgyOTJjNjM0YmEyMDllMCIsInQiOjE2ODIzMjI2ODUsInN0ZnAiOm51bGwsInN0aXAiOm51bGx9.wHIMzT4EdVvErh625hc2cOlVfge51l0_lcC067fEqWM/Solarized-Dark-Cyan-3.0.3.tar

The issue is the links can not be found in the page source. They are hidden behind tabs (triggered via js).

I am not understanding how to get the links of these files via cli.

I am not hung up on curl. Any too will work as long as I can get the links via CLI.

Comment: Are you aware of https://www.opendesktop.org/ocs-api ?

Comment: Yes I know, but i have to write a script that will download some themes and icons. That is why need to get the files via cli.

Comment: well, but you want to use a website which offers an API, so you should probably use a tool that speaks that API; no matter whether you do this in shell or say in python, you'll be scripting it, so I'd really recommend you don't try to shoehorn a web api usage problem into a command line problem.

Comment: The following command give url of all the downloadable files `curl -Lfs https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1308808/loadFiles | perl -pe 's/\%(\w\w)/chr hex $1/ge' | jq .`. However, I want the latest one (in this particular case 3.0.3). Not understanding how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To download the latest versions of the themes or icons, use the following command.

```
curl -Lfs https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1308808/loadFiles | jq -r '.files | first.version as $v | .[] | select(.version == $v).url' | perl -pe 's/\%(\w\w)/chr hex $1/ge' | xargs wget
```

or:

```
curl -Lfs https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1308808/loadFiles | jq -r --arg version "$(curl -Lfs https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1308808/loadFiles | jq -r '.files | .[0] | .version')" '.files | .[] | select(.version==$version) | .url' | perl -pe 's/\%(\w\w)/chr hex $1/ge' | xargs wget
```

To download all files use

```
curl -Lfs https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1308808/loadFiles | jq -r '.files | .[] | .url' | perl -pe 's/\%(\w\w)/chr hex $1/ge' | xargs wget
```